# Unintuitive behavior of "Suggested Edits" review queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Today, I found an [edit suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/392223) in my review queue where the [question that was to be edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/674303/377345) had already been deleted. It looks like a moot point to keep such items in the review queue.

Is this a bug, or was this still somehow intended behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like intended behavior. From [Reject or approve suggested edits on deleted post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359913/307535):

> Our reviewing FAQ on handling suggested edits outlines why you would approve or reject a suggested edit and, you may notice, that it makes no mention of deleted posts - because it just isn't a consideration treat them the same.

There's another MSE post on the topic, which isn't Answered by staff: [What happens to a pending suggested edit when a post is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337667/307535) which says, in part:

> It sits in the queue for the next reviewer

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the MSE post. Sounds ok to me! Do you want to add `status-bydesign` to the question?

Comment: Maybe. Sounded like there were intentions to change the behavior at some point, so I'm not sure what the "design" is at this point :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363151/703623 then https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306875/703623